# Hashcode for string in different machine returns same value

Tags: java, hashcode

I have read that hashcode in a JVM instance returns same value. But in another JVM instance, the same value may not be returned.
I tried the following program:

```
public class demo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = new String("Hello");
    System.out.println(s.hashCode());
 }
}
```

This program returns the same value as many number of times I rerun it on my machine. Also, I tried running the same program on other machines and everywhere I got the same value. Is it just coincidence?

I have a scenario where based on a strings value i'll determine the next business logic to follow. So currently I am doing

```
switch(s.hashcode()%4){
      case 0:....
      case 1:....
}
```

Should this work fine always?

Comment: Hash code is derived from your string, so equal strings will have equal hash values. It's no coincidence.

Comment: If it's possible for java to modify the implementation of String's hashCode implementation between versions, then it's possible for two instances of java to return different hash codes (if they were different versions). I think they are saying the values aren't guaranteed to be the same, not that they are guaranteed to be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether the hashCode is the same across runs or not (whether it is *deterministic*) depends on the class. For example, String has a deterministic hashCode; Object does not. In general, you should not expect hashCode to be deterministic.

Furthermore, hashCode isn't random either. Object's hashCode, for example, is just the object's memory address, which might always be divisible by 4//